# Is there any special adjective like 'award-winning'?

Tags: continuous, present-continuous

OALD says...

> [award-winning (adj)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/award-winning) -*having **won** a prize*

I'm a bit surprised having the *participle* there. Why? Because the action is *completed* and still it uses the continuous tense (CT).

I thought of similar adjective *thought-provoking*. OALD says...

> [thought-provoking (adj)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/thought-provoking) - *<del>not made</del> **making** people think seriously about a particular subject or issue*

And, I'm pretty sure, there are many such adjectives.

What makes the former one unique is the thing that has ***already happened*** ('won' awards, not 'winning' or going to 'win') but still using the CT.

Are there other such adjectives that refer to *past* but in its adjective, takes CT?

Comment: "Good question, but the continuous (or progressive) form is not a tense―it doesn't locate events in time." -- snailboat

Comment: @DamkerngT. I wanted to talk about the things that happen now, in present tense. So used it! Copy to snail!

Comment: Perhaps the most common one (for learners) is *interesting*. I'd say these are formed fundamentally the same way (i.e. by using the present participle form of the verb). -- (Note that that's my own opinion.)

Comment: It's not a gerund but a participle.

Answer (score 3):

As Damkerng T (citing snailboat) points out, participles do not express tense. They may express ‘voice’, agency/patiency: the *-ing* form may in some contexts be characterized as an *active* participle and the *-en* form as a passive participle.

They may also express (or at least reflect) [*aspect*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info); but *what* aspect they express depends on the complicated interaction of syntactic and pragmatic context and the verb's inherent semantics.

Broadly it may be said that the *-ing* form of any *achievement* verb (or any verb which in the immediate context is to be understood as bearing the *achievement* aspect) may be used this way.

Consider for instance:

> Taxpayers **filing** late may be subject to a penalty.

Clearly the IRS does not restrict your liability to the instant when you file your return, and before you file you are a non-filer (which has, I imagine, different penalties). What is meant is *Taxpayers who **have filed** late.*

Likewise:

> Examinees **finishing** before the end of the examination period may leave.

You cannot leave *while* you are finishing your exam, only after you ***have finished*** it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of examples to show that "logical" *past/ongoing* isn't always directly reflected by verb tense...

> [*The Japanese are a long-**lived** race*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
>    [*Bamboo is a fast-**growing** plant*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Bamboo%20is%20a%20fast-growing%20plant%22&tbm=bks)

I don't think we can really call *award-winning, fast-growing,* etc. "gerunds" (they're not "nouns" in any meaningful sense), but I don't know what to call them apart from "verb-derived adjectives".

---

If we compare...

> 3: [*He was wearing a moth-**eaten** sweater and tattered jeans*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22wearing%20a%20moth-eaten%20sweater%20and%20tattered%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:2000%2Ccd_max:2099)
>    4: [*[Peppered moths'] behavior and coloration camouflage them from day-**flying**, moth-**eating** birds.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22from%20day-flying%20moth-eating%20birds%22&tbm=bks)
>    5: [*Grandmother saw him as a heart**broken** man desperately trying to win back the one he loved.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22him%20as%20a%20heartbroken%20man%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:2000%2Ccd_max:2099)
>    6: [*It was a heart**breaking** tale of sexual and physical abuse*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a%20heartbreaking%20tale%20of%20sexual%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1%2Ccd_min:2000%2Ccd_max:2099)

...I think this illustrates a useful general principle...

> The ***-ing*** forms denote *activities performed **by** the "subject"*, whereas the past tense forms tend to denote *things done **to** the subject*.

As it happens, #1 above violates that principle. But that's just an idiomatic peculiarity of one particular word-pair (it's worth noting that although less common, [*a long-**living** species*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20Japanese%20are%20a%20long-lived%20race%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a%20long-living%20species%22&tbas=0&tbm=bks) is perfectly okay).

---

Thus we see that OP's specific *award-**winning*** example adheres to the general principle. The fact that at least *some* awards were won in the past is almost incidental (an *award-**winning** actor* can be understood as someone who *has won*, and *may continue to win* awards).